# Extjs 4.2: Row Editing Width issue in case of Multiple instance of Custom Component

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have multiple instance of my custom xtype(grid). One of them has been inserted in one view at compile time but others are dynamically inserted in other views in afterrender event like:

```
var cmp = Ext.getCmp('secondTab');
cmp.insert(cmp.items.length, {xtype: 'customGrid',  id:'customGrid2'});
```

Everything is working fine. Issues is with the rowEditing plugin. When I open tab in which my custom Grid is present it looks like this(correct one):

[image]

But when I open some other tab which also contains instance of my custom Grid it looks like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me that what can be possible issue?

Code for row editing plugin is simple:

```
plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        pluginId: 'rowEditing',
        autoCancel: false,

        // Preventing editing mode by click on any cell
        onCellClick: function ( view, cell, colIdx, record, row, rowIdx, e){} ,
        startEditByClick: function (){},
        onEnterKey: function (){},

        // Listening various event of plugin
        listeners: {

            /**
             * @event edit
             * Fires after a editing
             * Calling respective controller method.
             * @param {Ext.grid.plugin.Editing} editor
             */
            edit: function(editor, e) {
                // I am calling my controller method here to add a new record in this grid code is  pasted here

                var store = Ext.getStore('teilgewerke_store_neu');
                var r = Ext.create('MyApp.model.MyModel',{'name': "", 'date':"", 'text' : ""});
                store.proxy.url = "someUrl";
                var result = store.add(r);

                var rowEditingPlugin = Ext.getCmp(this.viewParentId).getPlugin('rowEditing');

                rowEditingPlugin.startEdit(r);

            },

            /**
             * @event canceledit
             * Fires when the user started editing but then cancelled the edit. Enable the Hinzufaugen Button and reload the grid.
             * @param {Ext.grid.plugin.Editing} editor
             */
            canceledit: function(editor, context, eOpt){

                //My own logic to enable disable stuff
            }
        }
    })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this issue. I don't know if this is the only or the best solution but I solved it by dynamically inserting the row editing plugin in to the various instances of my custom grid.

So after dynamic insertion of the Grid, I inserted the row editing plugins like:

```
//code for row editing plugin given in my question but just for sample
var plugin = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {

        onCellClick: function ( view, cell, colIdx, record, row, rowIdx, e){} ,
        startEditByClick: function (){},
        onEnterKey: function (){},

        listeners: {
            edit: function(editor, e) {
                //Whatever you want to do
            }
        }
    })

var myGrid = Ext.getCmp('instanceOfMyCustomGrid');
plugin.init(myGrid); //This is important while dynamically inserting plugin
myGrid.plugins = []; // If there is no other plugin for your grid, create an empty plugin array
myGrid.plugins[0] = plugin; //Insert your plugin
```

That's it. It worked for me. If anyone still knows a better solution, Kindly do post.